# Add f:param in p:tabMenu programmatically

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to add `<f:param name="id" value="val" />` to menuItem? It need this to achieve effect pushed button when site connected with button is actual site.

```
            <h:form style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">  
                <p:growl id="growl" life="2000" />
                <p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{param.id}" model="#{tabMenuView.model}" />
            </h:form>
```

Something like this:

```
                <h:form>
                    <p:growl id="growl" life="2000" />
                    <p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{param.id}">

                        <p:menuitem value="Overview" url="?id=0">
                            <f:param name="id" value="0" />
                        </p:menuitem>
                    </p:tabMenu>
                </h:form>
```

I do not know how to in ManagedBean add

```
<f:param
```

My ManagedBean looks like this.

```
@ManagedBean
public class TabMenuView
{
    private MenuModel model;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        model = new DefaultMenuModel();

        DefaultMenuItem item;
        item = new DefaultMenuItem("Name");
        item.setUrl("?id=" + "1");
        model.addElement(item);
    }
```

Comment: `f:param` is plain jsf so I added that tag